Excel LET Formula Results in #CALC! Error When Applying a Filter
I am trying to create a formula that shows a list of Top 20 staff names based on a grouped count. Futhermore, I am trying to dynamically apply a filter to said list.
The data is being taken from the following table NoCstNoAcr, that consists of a list of users, their respective company and branch.
I can successfully show the top 20 usernames based on the file count - but when I try to apply a branch filter (i.e., show the top 20 usernames in a specific branch grouped by file count), the formula returns #CALC! due to nested arrays.
Below is my code:
=LET(
    branchFilter; D33;
    NoCstNoAcrHeaders; NoCstNoAcr[#Headers];
    branchIndex; MATCH("Branch Code"; NoCstNoAcrHeaders; 0);
    operatorIndex; MATCH("Operator Full Name"; NoCstNoAcrHeaders; 0);
    filteredData; IF(ISBLANK(branchFilter);
                     NoCstNoAcr;
                     FILTER(NoCstNoAcr; INDEX(NoCstNoAcr[Branch Code];;)=branchFilter));
    operatorNames; UNIQUE(INDEX(filteredData;;operatorIndex));
    fileCounts; MAP(operatorNames; LAMBDA(name; COUNTIF(INDEX(filteredData;;operatorIndex); name)));
    sortedData; SORTBY(HSTACK(operatorNames; fileCounts); fileCounts; -1);
    TAKE(sortedData; 20)
)

The branch filter is residing in cell D33.
Can someone help me understand why this error occurs and how to fix the formula so it works correctly when a branch filter is applied?

Does COUNTIF() function works with an array? Try to amend this : MAP(operatorNames; LAMBDA(name; SUM(N(INDEX(filteredData;;operatorIndex)=name)))) also there is no sample data posted.

WIth COUNTIFS instead
I think the error is due to COUNTIF's first parameter, as it cannot be an array (only range).
I wonder whether you could try this to get the fileCounts:

Using COUNTIFS get counts matching names and branch.
Combine with Names.
Get unique rows with name, count.
Filter out rows with zero count.

(Please change , to ;)
=LET(
    branchFilter, D33,
    fileCounts_step1, UNIQUE(
        HSTACK(
            NoCstNoAcr[Operator Full Name],
            COUNTIFS(
                NoCstNoAcr[Operator Full Name], NoCstNoAcr[Operator Full Name],
                NoCstNoAcr[Branch Code], IF(
                        LEN(TRIM(branchFilter)) > 0,
                        branchFilter,
                        NoCstNoAcr[Branch Code]
                    )
            )
        )
    ),
    fileCounts, FILTER(fileCounts_step1, INDEX(fileCounts_step1, , 2) > 0),
    sortedData, SORT(fileCounts, 2, -1),
    result, TAKE(sortedData, 20),
    IFERROR(result, "No results")
)

Or
=LAMBDA(branchFilter, top,
    LET(
        fileCounts_step1, UNIQUE(
            HSTACK(
                NoCstNoAcr[Operator Full Name],
                COUNTIFS(
                    NoCstNoAcr[Operator Full Name], NoCstNoAcr[Operator Full Name],
                    NoCstNoAcr[Branch Code], IF(
                        LEN(TRIM(branchFilter)) > 0,
                        branchFilter,
                        NoCstNoAcr[Branch Code]
                    )
                )
            )
        ),
        fileCounts, FILTER(fileCounts_step1, INDEX(fileCounts_step1, , 2) > 0),
        sortedData, SORT(fileCounts, 2, -1),
        result, TAKE(sortedData, 20),
        IFERROR(result, "No results")
    )
)(D33, 20)


Thanks! Now the formula works if there is a branch filter (D33 is NOT empty). However, if  D33 is empty, it shows "No Results".

Ah, yes, I wasn't sure what should be the result. I've changed the condition in the answer to IF(LEN(TRIM(branchFilter)) > 0, branchFilter, NoCstNoAcr[Branch Code]) - could you please try and see whether it is what you want?

Count Unique Filtered

To make it flexible, try the following.

=LET(list,NoCstNoAcr[#All],unique_header,"Operator Full Name",
        filter_header,"Branch Code",filter_value,D33,top,D34,
    h,TAKE(list,1),
    d,DROP(list,1),
    ud,XLOOKUP(unique_header,h,d),
    fd,XLOOKUP(filter_header,h,d),
    f,IF(ISBLANK(filter_value),ud,FILTER(ud,fd=filter_value)),
    u,UNIQUE(f),
    c,BYROW(u,LAMBDA(r,ROWS(FILTER(f,f=r)))),
    s,SORTBY(u,c,-1),
    r,TAKE(s,top),
    r)



To reap the benefits of an Excel table, try the following.

=LET(filter_value,D33,top,D34,
    ud,NoCstNoAcr[Operator Full Name],
    fd,NoCstNoAcr[Branch Code],
    f,IF(ISBLANK(filter_value),ud,FILTER(ud,fd=filter_value)),
    u,UNIQUE(f),
    c,BYROW(u,LAMBDA(r,ROWS(FILTER(f,f=r)))),
    s,SORTBY(u,c,-1),
    r,TAKE(s,top),
    r)


Replace the last occurrence of r with any other variable to see what it holds. Note that the r variable in the BYROW function is a different variable.
Rename the variables as you see fit, e.g.:

h - headers,
d - data,
ud - names,
fd - branches,
f - filtered_names,
u - distinct_names,
c - counts,
s - sorted,
r - result.



